# How to fix an out-of-range string index?

Tags: java, string

I've run into the following problem with my program (only on attempting to run it, builds fine):

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: 
String index out of range: 57
at java.lang.String.substring(String.java:1907)
at Question7.main(Question7.java:68)
```

I know there are similar questions on the site, but I'm going through the steps in my head and can't figure out where this is going wrong. 
I don't think the context of the code/question asked is very important; I believe the problem has something to do with the following lines:

```
else if (s1.substring(i,i+1).matches("[0-9]"))

if (counthyphen == 3 && countdigits == 9 && (s1.substring(i, i+1).matches("[0-9]") || s1.substring(i, i+1).matches("X")))
```

But please, have a look for yourself. Help would be much appreciated!

```
public class Question7
{
public static void main(String args[])
{
    //Declare and initialize.
    String s1 = new String("0-471-34609-8");
    int counthyphen = 0, countdigits = 0;

    //Begin "for" loop.
    for (int i = 0; i < s1.length()-1; i++)
    {
        /////////////////////////////////
        // Check for missing hyphens //
        if (s1.charAt(1) != '-')
        {
            i = s1.length();
        }
        else if (s1.charAt(11) != '-')
        {
            i = s1.length();
        }

        // Now add to the count values //
        if (s1.charAt(i) == '-')
        {
            counthyphen++;
        }
        **else if (s1.substring(i,i+1).matches("[0-9]"))**
        {
            countdigits++;
        }
        /////////////////////////////////
    }

    int i = s1.charAt(s1.length()-1);
    //Check if it's an ISBN and print result.
    **if (counthyphen == 3 && countdigits == 9 && (s1.substring(i, i+1).matches("[0-9]") || s1.substring(i, i+1).matches("X")))**
    {
        System.out.print("This number is an ISBN.");
    }
    else
    {
        System.out.print("This number is NOT an ISBN.");
    }
}
}
```

Comment: Why do you assign the same value to `i`: `i = s1.length();` in the `if` and in the `else`?

Comment: First you should think how you would write that logic without having to modify that `i` within the loop. It's a bad practice.

Comment: If my code is ugly, please tell me what's wrong with it? I've been coding for 1 month, still going through the very basics. That said, I assigned the "i" value within the if and else statements in order to break the loop. My lecturer wasn't very clear on the point that "break;" is a faster way to get out of a loop.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
int i = s1.charAt(s1.length()-1);
```

This code stores the `ASCII code` of the `character` at the index : - `s1.length() - 1`, that can `certainly` be greater than the `maximum` accessible string index.

**For e.g**, the `last` character in your current string is `8`, whose `ASCII code` is: - `56`, and that would certainly fail.

So, `s1.substring(i, i+1)` in your if condition after that would fail.

In fact, I don't understand the need of that line at all. Why are you using it?

---

Also, your `if-else` block seems `buggy` to me: -

```
    if (s1.charAt(1) != '-')
    {
        i = s1.length();
    }
    else if (s1.charAt(11) != '-')
    {
        i = s1.length();
    }
```

Why have you assigned same value to `i` in both the blocks there?

**May be** you wanted something like this: -

```
    if (s1.charAt(1) != '-' || s1.charAt(11) != '-')
    {
        break;  // Just break if not a valid string
    }
```

Comment: There are 13 characters/digits in my String. Doesn't this mean that the maximum index is 12, and if I keep "i" below 12 I'll stay within the index?


As for s1.substring(i,i+1)...isn't that how you select a specific character in the String? For example, if i is 3 then it would look like this: s1.substring(3, 4) and the character at index position 3 would be selected, ie "7". I then intended to find out whether this was an integer digit with: .matches("[0-9]").


Thank you very much for the assistance.

Answer (score 0):

You are starting your for loop at zero index.

for (int i = 0; i < s1.length()-1; i++)

Yet your substring goes beyond i in the following code,

.substring(i, i+1).

On an optimizing note, you may use regexp to check for the hyphen at index 1 and 11.

Comment: no no no.. the loop index is not the reason. It is running fine. Had it been `i <= s1.length() - 1`, or `i < s1.length()`, then it would have been a problem.